# Applications of SGD outside learning tasks

Tags: optimization, soft-question, applications, gradient-descent

**Are there applications, outside of machine learning, where stochastic gradient descent (SGD) is the preferred method of optimization?**

By SGD, I mean any first-order method which approximates the true gradient with a noisy estimate. I'm especially (but not only) interested in any applications where SGD is not employed for its greater computational efficiency, but for the possible regularization properties of the noise.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's used in signal processing or (non-ML) engineering applications as a generic method for smooth optimization. Usually when I see it, it's because they wanted an easily implementable method though -- not because of any inherent merit or regularization-effect based on the noise in the algorithm.

(However, that's just what I've seen - take it with a grain of salt.)